# Return a line from a document and display this

Tags: c#

I feel a little silly posting this but I have looked everywhere and I have been unable to find the answer.

I have an application that loops through a group of documents and if a document contains a value in create a dialog box for the user to update the value. The problem I am having is that I want the Dialog box to display not only the value but 10 characters after lets say it is looking for `$` as the value.

my current codes looks like the following:

```
if (script.Contains("$"))
{
    string promptValue = CreateInput.ShowDialog("Update Name", "Name");                 
    script.Replace("$", promptValue);                  
}
```

I know I can use string.contains but I am not sure on how to get this to display in my dialog.

**Edit**

To be more specific I am looking for a way to return a sub-string of an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Substring` method, like this:

```
if (script.Contains("$"))
{
    int dollarIndex = script.IndexOf("$");
    string nextTenChars = script.Substring(dollarIndex+1, 10);
    //rest of your code
}
```

*edit:*
as Adwaenyth said in comment, use this approach if task ist that simple (and `script` is relatively short string). In case of greater complexity, use regular expressions.

Comment: Either that or use Regular Expressions if the condition gets more complex.

Comment: Be aware that this code will fail when the `$` is at the end-10 chars of the document

Comment: If there are less then 10 `chars` after the `$` there will be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Nino, This worked however, how would you use regular expressions would this not through an error because of the int?

Comment: @Tom, you can always supress error by checking if remaining text lenght, after `$` is greater of equal to 10 and if not take whats available. But, those string operations can be very slow if text is large (megabytes of text). So, instead of substring, you could use something like this `\$.{1,10}` (this regex tells to find $ and then take any character,  between 1 and 10 times, as many times as possible

Comment: @MightyBadaboom , Please can you remove this question from on hold? this was answered by Nino.